# How do I get audio from Android into libPD?

Tags: java, android, audio, puredata, libpd

Based on Peter Brinkmann's sample class, I am running libpd and processing in Eclipse. But I don't seem to completely understand how to get the audio input from the Android microphone into Pure Data.

when I run it on an actual or virtual device, I get a bunch of errors saying:

E/AudioRecord(1079): Could not get audio input for record source 1

E/AudioRecord-JNI(1079): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.

Here's the main Class:

```
package com.noisepages.nettoyeur.processing.sample;

import org.puredata.android.io.AudioParameters;
import org.puredata.android.processing.PureDataP5Android;
import processing.core.PApplet;

/**
* @author Peter Brinkmann (peter.brinkmann@gmail.com)
*/
public class PdP5Sample extends PApplet {

PureDataP5Android pd;
int zipId = com.noisepages.nettoyeur.processing.sample.R.raw.patch; // Processing masks R
int ins = AudioParameters.suggestInputChannels();
int sampleRate = AudioParameters.suggestSampleRate();


public void setup() {

    pd = new PureDataP5Android(this, sampleRate, ins, 2);

    pd.unpackAndOpenPatch(zipId, "audiotest.pd");

    pd.start();

}

public void draw() {
    background(0);
    fill(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
    stroke(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100);


}

public void stop() {
    pd.release();
    super.stop();
}

/*
// Implement methods like the following if you want to receive messages from Pd.
// You'll also need to subscribe to receive symbols you're interested if you want
// to receive messages.

public void pdPrint(String s) {
    // Handle string s, printed by Pd
}

public void receiveBang(String source) {
    // Handle bang sent to symbol source in Pd
}

public void receiveFloat(String source, float x) {
    // Handle float x sent to symbol source in Pd
}

public void receiveSymbol(String source, String sym) {
    // Handle symbol sym sent to symbol source in Pd
}
*/

// boilerplate
public int sketchWidth() { return this.screenWidth; }
public int sketchHeight() { return this.screenHeight; }
public String sketchRenderer() { return PApplet.OPENGL; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add this to AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```